# Solidity Smart Contract Parse Error Help - Full Contract Included Within

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am receiving a `ParseError` at the end of my contract. I've vetted through and tried reformatting, editing, deleting, and triple checking braces but I can't find the issue. It could be something simple that I'm missing, I'm just not able to track it down. What is the compiler expecting here? I've included the contract below. Let me know if you need any more information.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Contract is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 public constant maxTokens = 6969;    
    uint256 public constant maxMintsPerTx = 10;
    uint256 public tokenPrice = 20000000000000000; //0.02 ether
    uint256 public startingBlock =999999999;
    string private _contractURI;
    string public provenance;
    uint256 public nextTokenId=1;
    bool public devMintLocked = false;
    bool private initialized = false;
    
     string[] private wrap = [
        "three"
    ];
    
    string[] private paper = [
        "two"
    ];
    
    string[] private second = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private first = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private format = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private next = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private suffixes = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private namePrefixes = [
        "two"
    ];
    
    string[] private nameSuffixes = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    function random(string memory input) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input)));
    }
    
    function getWrap(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "WRAP", wrap);
    }
    
    function getPaper(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "PAPER", paper);
    }
    
    function getSecond(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "SECOND", second);
    }
    
    function getFirst(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "FIRST", first);
    }

    function getFormat(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "FORMAT", format);
    }
    
    function getNext(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "NEXT", next);
    }
    
    
    function pluck(uint256 tokenId, string memory keyPrefix, string[] memory sourceArray) internal view returns (string memory) {
        uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked(keyPrefix, toString(tokenId))));
        string memory output = sourceArray[rand % sourceArray.length];
        uint256 greatness = rand % 21;
        if (greatness > 14) {
            output = string(abi.encodePacked(output, " ", suffixes[rand % suffixes.length]));
        }
        if (greatness >= 19) {
            string[2] memory name;
            name[0] = namePrefixes[rand % namePrefixes.length];
            name[1] = nameSuffixes[rand % nameSuffixes.length];
            if (greatness == 19) {
                output = string(abi.encodePacked('"', name[0], ' ', name[1], '" ', output));
            } else {
                output = string(abi.encodePacked('"', name[0], ' ', name[1], '" ', output, " +1"));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) override public view returns (string memory) {
        string[17] memory parts;
        parts[0] = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 400 400"><style>.base { fill: #71FF7B; font-family: "Roboto Mono"; font-size: 10px; }</style><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#06420D" /><text x="10" y="20" class="base">';

        parts[1] = getWrap(tokenId);

        parts[2] = '</text><text x="10" y="40" class="base">';

        parts[3] = getPaper(tokenId);

        parts[4] = '</text><text x="10" y="60" class="base">';

        parts[5] = getSecond(tokenId);

        parts[6] = '</text><text x="10" y="80" class="base">';

        parts[7] = getFirst(tokenId);

        parts[8] = '</text><text x="10" y="100" class="base">';

        parts[9] = getFormat(tokenId);

        parts[10] = '</text><text x="10" y="120" class="base">';

        parts[11] = getNext(tokenId);

        parts[13] = '</text></svg>';

        string memory output = string(abi.encodePacked(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7], parts[8]));
        output = string(abi.encodePacked(output, parts[9], parts[10], parts[11], parts[12], parts[13], parts[14], parts[15], parts[16]));
        
        string memory json = Base64.encode(bytes(string(abi.encodePacked('{"name": "Mint #', toString(tokenId), '", "description": "Welcome to the contract. Be healthy, be happy. Do whatever you want with these. WAGMI.", "image": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,', Base64.encode(bytes(output)), '"}'))));
        output = string(abi.encodePacked('data:application/json;base64,', json));

        return output;
    }
    
     function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {

    // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT license
    // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            digits -= 1;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }
        return string(buffer);
    }


    constructor()
        public
        ERC721("Contract", "CONTRACT") {}
}

    //Set Base URI
    function setBaseURI(string memory _baseURI) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        _setBaseURI(_baseURI);
    }


    //Set Contract-level URI
    function setContractURI(string memory contractURI_) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        _contractURI = contractURI_;
    }


    //View Contract-level URI
    function contractURI() 
        public 
        view 
        returns (string memory) 
    {
        return _contractURI;
    }

    //Provenance may only be set once irreversibly
    function setProvenance(string memory _provenance) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        require(
            bytes(provenance).length == 0,
             "Provenance already set!"
             );
        provenance = _provenance;
    }
    
    //Minting
    function reup(uint256 quantity) 
        external 
        payable 
    {
        require(
             block.number >= startingBlock,
             "Sale hasn't started yet!"
        );
        require(
            quantity <= maxMintsPerTx,
            "There is a limit on minting too many at a time."
        );
        require(
            nextTokenId -1 + quantity <= maxTokens ,
            "Minting this many would exceed supply."
        );
        require(
            msg.value >= tokenPrice * quantity,
            "Not enough ether sent."
        );
        require(
            msg.sender == tx.origin,
            "No contracts."
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, nextTokenId++);
        }
    }

    //Dev mint special tokens
    function mintSpecial(address [] memory recipients, uint256 [] memory specialId) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {        
        require (!devMintLocked,
            "Dev Mint Permanently Locked"
            );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            require (specialId[i]!=0);
            _safeMint(recipients[i],specialId[i]*1000000);
        }
    }

    function setStartingBlock(uint256 _startingBlock)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        startingBlock=_startingBlock;
    }

    function lockDevMint()
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        devMintLocked=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the full error message - getting it on the last brace.

ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
--> contract.sol:447:1:
|
447 | }
| ^

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the wrong `}`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AFL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Contract is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 public constant maxTokens = 6969;    
    uint256 public constant maxMintsPerTx = 10;
    uint256 public tokenPrice = 20000000000000000; //0.02 ether
    uint256 public startingBlock =999999999;
    string private _contractURI;
    string public provenance;
    uint256 public nextTokenId=1;
    bool public devMintLocked = false;
    bool private initialized = false;
    
     string[] private wrap = [
        "three"
    ];
    
    string[] private paper = [
        "two"
    ];
    
    string[] private second = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private first = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private format = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private next = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private suffixes = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    string[] private namePrefixes = [
        "two"
    ];
    
    string[] private nameSuffixes = [
        "one"
    ];
    
    function random(string memory input) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input)));
    }
    
    function getWrap(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "WRAP", wrap);
    }
    
    function getPaper(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "PAPER", paper);
    }
    
    function getSecond(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "SECOND", second);
    }
    
    function getFirst(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "FIRST", first);
    }

    function getFormat(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "FORMAT", format);
    }
    
    function getNext(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return pluck(tokenId, "NEXT", next);
    }
    
    
    function pluck(uint256 tokenId, string memory keyPrefix, string[] memory sourceArray) internal view returns (string memory) {
        uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked(keyPrefix, toString(tokenId))));
        string memory output = sourceArray[rand % sourceArray.length];
        uint256 greatness = rand % 21;
        if (greatness > 14) {
            output = string(abi.encodePacked(output, " ", suffixes[rand % suffixes.length]));
        }
        if (greatness >= 19) {
            string[2] memory name;
            name[0] = namePrefixes[rand % namePrefixes.length];
            name[1] = nameSuffixes[rand % nameSuffixes.length];
            if (greatness == 19) {
                output = string(abi.encodePacked('"', name[0], ' ', name[1], '" ', output));
            } else {
                output = string(abi.encodePacked('"', name[0], ' ', name[1], '" ', output, " +1"));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) override public view returns (string memory) {
        string[17] memory parts;
        parts[0] = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 400 400"><style>.base { fill: #71FF7B; font-family: "Roboto Mono"; font-size: 10px; }</style><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#06420D" /><text x="10" y="20" class="base">';

        parts[1] = getWrap(tokenId);

        parts[2] = '</text><text x="10" y="40" class="base">';

        parts[3] = getPaper(tokenId);

        parts[4] = '</text><text x="10" y="60" class="base">';

        parts[5] = getSecond(tokenId);

        parts[6] = '</text><text x="10" y="80" class="base">';

        parts[7] = getFirst(tokenId);

        parts[8] = '</text><text x="10" y="100" class="base">';

        parts[9] = getFormat(tokenId);

        parts[10] = '</text><text x="10" y="120" class="base">';

        parts[11] = getNext(tokenId);

        parts[13] = '</text></svg>';

        string memory output = string(abi.encodePacked(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7], parts[8]));
        output = string(abi.encodePacked(output, parts[9], parts[10], parts[11], parts[12], parts[13], parts[14], parts[15], parts[16]));
        
        string memory json = Base64.encode(bytes(string(abi.encodePacked('{"name": "Mint #', toString(tokenId), '", "description": "Welcome to the contract. Be healthy, be happy. Do whatever you want with these. WAGMI.", "image": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,', Base64.encode(bytes(output)), '"}'))));
        output = string(abi.encodePacked('data:application/json;base64,', json));

        return output;
    }
    
     function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {

    // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT license
    // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            digits -= 1;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }
        return string(buffer);
    }


    constructor()
        public
        ERC721("Contract", "CONTRACT") {}


    //Set Base URI
    function setBaseURI(string memory _baseURI) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        _setBaseURI(_baseURI);
    }


    //Set Contract-level URI
    function setContractURI(string memory contractURI_) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        _contractURI = contractURI_;
    }


    //View Contract-level URI
    function contractURI() 
        public 
        view 
        returns (string memory) 
    {
        return _contractURI;
    }

    //Provenance may only be set once irreversibly
    function setProvenance(string memory _provenance) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        require(
            bytes(provenance).length == 0,
             "Provenance already set!"
             );
        provenance = _provenance;
    }
    
    //Minting
    function reup(uint256 quantity) 
        external 
        payable 
    {
        require(
             block.number >= startingBlock,
             "Sale hasn't started yet!"
        );
        require(
            quantity <= maxMintsPerTx,
            "There is a limit on minting too many at a time."
        );
        require(
            nextTokenId -1 + quantity <= maxTokens ,
            "Minting this many would exceed supply."
        );
        require(
            msg.value >= tokenPrice * quantity,
            "Not enough ether sent."
        );
        require(
            msg.sender == tx.origin,
            "No contracts."
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, nextTokenId++);
        }
    }

    //Dev mint special tokens
    function mintSpecial(address [] memory recipients, uint256 [] memory specialId) 
        external 
        onlyOwner 
    {        
        require (!devMintLocked,
            "Dev Mint Permanently Locked"
            );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            require (specialId[i]!=0);
            _safeMint(recipients[i],specialId[i]*1000000);
        }
    }

    function setStartingBlock(uint256 _startingBlock)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        startingBlock=_startingBlock;
    }

    function lockDevMint()
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        devMintLocked=true;
    }

}
```